# Seaborn's heatmap not displaying all values

Tags: seaborn, heatmap

I was trying to visualize some data I got from a confusion matrix using sklearn, but as you can see in the next image, the second row of the seaborn heatmap is not showing the values.

[image: Seaborn heatmap problem]

I tried to replicate the error in google collab and there it worked perfectly as you can see:

[image: Google collab heatmap]

The next thing I did was check the seaborn version, and in both my pc and google collab was 12.2.0

Comment: This is a known bug.

Comment: Consider upgrading seaborn to version 0.13 (the problem is related to both the matplotlib and the seaborn version)

Comment: @JohanC Yep, upgrading to 0.13 solved the problem, thanks!